# Microsoft Graph explorer API gives unexpected error 403

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to read the events of another user using the API https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_email_id}/calendar/events

I am getting the expected results if i use graph explorer in the browser but the API call gives error 403.

> "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403"

Comment: Just to be clear, that call is successful when using Graph Explorer, but returns a 403 in another scenario? What is the other scenario?

Comment: The other scenario is when i try to use the API call from an android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, just needed to add another permission Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared.